# Postgres: group by and get most frequent value, plus count of matching foreign keys

Tags: postgresql

I am working in Postgres 9.6. I have a table called `person` that looks like this:

```
 id         | integer (pk)        
 name       | character varying(300) 
 name_slug  | character varying(50)
```

And another table called `person_to_manor` that looks like this, where `person_id` is a foreign key to `person.id`:

```
 id        | integer (pk)
 manor_id  | integer
 person_id | integer
```

I want to combine these two tables to populate a third table `canonical_person` in which the primary key is `name_slug`, and which has the following fields:

```
 name_slug  | character varying(50) (pk)
 name       | character varying(300) 
 num_manor  | integer
```

where:

- `name_slug` is the primary key
- `name` is the most common value of `person.name` when grouped by `name_slug`
- `num_l66` is the count of rows in `person_to_manor` that match any of the values of `id` for that value of `name_slug`.

Is this possible in a single SQL query? This is as far as I've got...

```
INSERT INTO canonical_person
VALUES (
  SELECT name_slug,
  [most popular value of name from `array_agg(distinct name) from person`],
  COUNT(number of rows in person_to_manor that match any of `array_agg(distinct id) from person`)
  FROM person
  GROUP BY name_slug);
```

Comment: How do you define "most popular"?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe as "the most common value of person.name when grouped by name_slug"

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this?

I created the three tables

```
CREATE TABLE test.person (
id int4 NOT NULL,
"name" varchar(300) NULL,
name_slug varchar(50) NULL,
CONSTRAINT person_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


CREATE TABLE test.person_to_manor (
id int4 NOT NULL,
manor_id int4 NULL,
person_id int4 NULL,
CONSTRAINT person_to_manor_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT person_to_manor_person_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES 
test.person(id)
);


CREATE TABLE test.canonical_person (
name_slug varchar(50) NOT NULL,
"name" varchar(300) NULL,
num_manor int4 NULL,
CONSTRAINT canonical_person_pkey PRIMARY KEY (name_slug)
);
```

With the following values

```
select * from test.person;

id|name|name_slug
--|----|---------
 0|a   |ab       
 1|b   |aa       
 2|c   |ab       
 3|a   |bb       
 4|a   |ab       


select * from test.person_to_manor;

id|manor_id|person_id
--|--------|---------
 1|       5|        0
 2|       6|        0
 3|       7|        2
```

I run this query

```
insert into  test.canonical_person
select name_slug,
       name as most_popular_name,
       sub.n as count_rows
from (
        select name,
               name_slug,count(*) as n,  
               row_number () over(order by count(*) desc)  as n_max
        from test.person 
        group by name,name_slug 
        order by n_max asc
     ) as sub
where sub.n_max =1;
```

The result after query

```
select * from test.canonical_person;

name_slug|name|num_manor
---------|----|---------
ab       |a   |        2
```

Is this your goal?

Comment: Please don't post images of output (or input, for that matter). Post as plain, formatted text.

Comment: Then, all record of person_to_manor are matching with the primary key of person's table, so what do you mean with "count of matching foreign keys"?